# Can I do a COUNT with a MySQL Join?

Tags: mysql, join, count, inner-join

This is my data

```
newCatCols
=====
id      sku     name
---------------
1           4001    Black
2           4031    Red
3           4021    Black
4           4041    Blush

products
=====
id      sku     Price
---------------
1           4001    123
2           4031    232
3           4021    453
4           4041    233
```

This is my query

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS numTotal
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `colors` ON `products`.`sku` = `colors`.`sku`
WHERE (
`name` = 'Apple_Black'
OR `name` = 'Black'
OR `name` = 'Black_Aubergine'
OR `name` = 'Black_Blush'
OR `name` = 'Black_Slate'
OR `name` = 'Black_Turquoise'
OR `name` = 'Red_Black'
OR `name` = 'Sapphire_Black'
OR `name` = 'Multi Apple'
)
AND `status` = '1'
AND `category` = 'sig'
GROUP BY `products`.`sku`
ORDER BY `products`.`rank` ASC
```

Ideally if I just change this line would be perfect `SELECT COUNT( * ) AS numTotal` somehow only modify that to make it work? The data currently returns a list of products with a row value of 1 so it is just looping and not counting the total value of all the rows.

It should should just show the total number on return, 4 for example should be shown

```
Output
 =====
 numTotal
 ---------------
 4
```

Comment: what exactly do you want? can you post your desired result?

Comment: Updated, it should just return the total values in the query. Currently it just loops all items

Comment: Because there are 4 records, so rather than loop those 4, it should just spit out the number 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the number of distinct product SKUs that match your criteria:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct `products`.`sku`) AS numTotal
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `colors` ON `products`.`sku` = `colors`.`sku`
WHERE `name` in ('Apple_Black'
        ,'Black'
        ,'Black_Aubergine'
        ,'Black_Blush'
        ,'Black_Slate'
        ,'Black_Turquoise'
        ,'Red_Black'
        ,'Sapphire_Black'
        ,'Multi Apple'
    )
    AND `status` = '1'
    AND `category` = 'sig'
```